# UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1 encoding in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to convert all &nbsp; instances to regular spaces in PHP:

```
echo '<meta charset="UTF-8" /> ';
echo html_entity_decode('&nbsp;');
echo html_entity_decode('&nbsp;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

If the first line is commented out, then the output will be in ISO 8859-1 and read:

```
 Â
```

Where there is a space in front. If UTF-8 encoding is specified, it reads:

```
�
```

Which is an undefined UTF-8 character followed by a space. Is there anyway to ensure that all HTML entity spaces are correctly decoded regardless of the encoding?

The space character is really just an example, what I am trying to do is read html input from an unspecified charset and display it. So < and &#60; would both become <.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem with encodings. They are not compatible. You have to use different options in `html_entity_decode` for every encoding. However, You may convert input to utf-8 ([iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)) first and use `html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')` later.

If You don't know the encoding of input, You have to guess.

Answer (score 4):

`&nbsp;` is not a space. It is the byte 160 in ISO 8859-1 and in UTF-8 it is `\xc2\xa0`. As the name `no breakable space` implies the browser will not replace it for a line break.

If you want a space you will have to replace it with a space.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is *a* space character, just not *the* space character.

Comment: @dan04 - it is only a space if rendered as html. As Chris answered the Content-type header should be set to html for the browser to render it as a space.

Answer (score 0):

Why not send a header first?

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
echo html_entity_decode("&nbsp;", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```